# 'if' statement not working in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to plot circles on a map at locations of tube stations. If the temperature at the station is less than 20 degrees, the 'stroke' of the circle must be white, otherwise black.

I tried many approaches and the following one is logically the simplest but it doesnot work can someone tell me why?

```
                    var stroke; // a global variable

 function ShowWeather(sId, place) {
            var h;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Station-Weather1.xml", 
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {`$(xml).find('DWStation').each(function () {
                        var stId = $(this).find("sId").text()

                        if (sId == stId) {
                            var cDate = getCurrentDate();
                            var wLocId = $(this).find("wId").text()

                            var wtURL = "http://localhost:56854/WebForm1.aspx?webURL=http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/xml/";


                            var wData;
                            $.ajax({
                                url: wtURL,
                                dataType: 'xml',
                                data: wData,
                                success: weatherData,
                                error: MyMessage
                            });

                            function weatherData(wData) {


                                var dv = $(wData).find("DV");

                                var tmp = dv.find("Location").find("Period").find("Rep");


                                  if (attrib.name == "T") { // In the corresponding XML file "T" is the "Temperature" value
```

`if (attrib.value < 20 ) {stroke = 1;} else {stroke =0;}
                                          } } } }); },});}`

```
        var data;


        $.ajax({
            url: "webURL=http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/feeds/cycle-hire/livecyclehireupdates.xml",
            dataType: 'xml', 
            data: data,
            success: parseXml,
            error: MyMessage
        });

        function parseXml(data) {
            var c;
            var color;
            var stations = d3.select(data).selectAll("station")[0];
            g.selectAll("circle")
                   .data(stations)
                   .enter()
                   .append("circle")
                   .style("fill", "red")
                   .attr("cx", function (d) {
                       return projection([d.getElementsByTagName("long")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue, d.getElementsByTagName("lat")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue])[0];
                   })
                   .attr("cy", function (d) {
                       return projection([d.getElementsByTagName("long")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue, d.getElementsByTagName("lat")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue])[1];
                   })
                   .attr("r", 3)


                   .style ("stroke", function(d)
                   {

               if (stroke == 1) { return c ="white"; } else { return c ="black"; }
                   })
```

Comment: _"it doesnot work can someone tell me why?"_ - What does happen? Is it just the colour selection that doesn't work, or...? Please be clearer about what doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You're making this more difficult than it needs to be -- you can do the checking for an attribute value and the setting of the colour in one place rather than split it out across several:

```
.style("stroke", function(d) { return d.T < 20 ? "white" : "black"; })
```

This assumes that your `stations` data that you bind to the circles has this attribute attached to it.

Comment: The temperature information is obtained from a different link and the station information is obtained from another link.

Comment: And how are those data linked up?

Comment: @user3297662 Consider nesting them into one object, then, using d3.nest() before entering the data(). Otherwise, you'll need to create loops. You never should use loops inside a d3 data function. http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff the temperature information helps determine what the colour of the circle stroke should be. The location of the pointer is obtained from the lat and lon information that is obtained in the station information. So for every station read from the XML file, a circle is plotted, while setting the "stroke" of the circle, I need to call the weather information, since the colour of the stroke depends on the weather. Hope it makes sense and doesnt sound complicated.

Comment: How are you matching up weather and station information?